# Proving that a polynomial is irreducible over $\mathbb{Q}$

Tags: abstract-algebra, irreducible-polynomials

How can I show that $f=t^4-8t^3/3+24t^2/9-32t/27+10/81$ is irreducible over $\mathbb{Q}$?

Comment: You can use [Eisenstein's criterion](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Eisenstein%27s_criterion) here, with $p = 2$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Result: Let $F$ be a field and $h$ be a nonzero element of $F$.  If $hf(x)$ is irreducible over $F$ then $f$ is irreducible over $F$

Now consider $$81f(t)=81t^4-216t^3+216t^2-96t+10$$ By Eisenstein criterion with prime $p=2$, this polynomial is irreducible and hence $f$ is irreducible